# Convert 4 bytes to integer using little-endian format (least signficant byte first)

Tags: ruby

According to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) page, the width of a `.bmp` image is stored in the header of the file, in bytes 0x12 through 0x15. For example, in an image that is 256x256, bytes 0x12 through 0x15 would look like this; Ruby converts each byte to an integer:

```
file = File.open("red_bmp.bmp", "r")
bytes = file.bytes.to_a
bytes[0x12..0x15]
#=> [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

In order to convert this to little-endian format, my best solution is to convert each decimal value to a hex string, reverse the array, join the elements, and convert the resulting hex string back to an integer.

```
width = bytes[0x12..0x15].map {|x| x.to_s(16).rjust(2, "0")}.reverse.join.to_i(16)
#=> 256
```

- Is there a simpler way to go about this?
- Is there an easy way to read a file and return an array of hex values instead of integers (without resorting to `x.to_s(16).rjust(2, "0")`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Byte wrangling in Ruby usually involves [`String#unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack) and [`Array#pack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack); in your case, you want to unpack some bytes into a native Ruby value so you want `String#unpack` and you want to use the `V` format:

```
V         | Integer | 32-bit unsigned, VAX (little-endian) byte order
```

I'd do something like this:

```
# The "b for binary" is important since you just want to deal with bytes
# and any encoding will get in the way.
fp = open(whatever, 'rb')

# Seek to the desired offset.
fp.seek(0x12)

# Read in four bytes.
s = fp.read(4)

# Unpack the bytes and the array:
two_fifty_six = s.unpack('V').first
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simpler way to go about this?

```
f =  File.open('mybmp.bmp',"wb")
str = [256, 256].pack "l>2"
p str     #"\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00"
f.write str
f.close

f = File.open('mybmp.bmp', "rb")
str = f.read 8
arr = str.unpack "l>2"
p arr     #[256, 256]

str = arr.pack("l<2")
p str    #"\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00"
```

> Is there an easy way to read a file and return an array of hex values instead of integers

Replace the last two lines above with this line:

```
p arr.map {|num| sprintf "%04x", num }  #["0100", "0100"]
```

Or, perhaps:

```
arr = str.unpack "h*"
results = []

arr[0].scan(/.{8}/) do |chars8|
  curr = ""

  chars8.scan(/.{2}/) do |chars2|
    curr << "\\x#{chars2}"
  end

  results << curr
end

p results     #["\\x00\\x00\\x10\\x00", "\\x00\\x00\\x10\\x00"]
```